# "and" in citation in the end of row

Tags: bibtex, line-breaking, citing, natbib

I write my article in Czech language where "and" = "a" and this little word can't be in the end of the row... how can I force bibtex not to write "and" (or anything else) in the end of the row in citations? For example I have: "some text and more you can find in book Little and
Rubin (2002)".. where "Little and Rubin (2002)" in automaticaly written by bibtex and "and = a" is unfortunately in the end, please help, thanks!! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which bibliography style do you use? (It's what's stored in the `.bst` file that tells BibTeX what to do.) How do you currently create citations? Do you use a citation management packages such as `natbib`, `harvard`, or `cite`?

Comment: Hi, I use natbib package and the file is czplainnat.bst... In text I use \cite.

Comment: @Mico I don't think that `" {\rm a~} "` would remove the space after the brace; rather `" \textrm{a}~"` Try `a~ b` and you'll see two spaces. In older versions of `amslatex` the tilde was redefined to do `\unskip` and `\ignorespaces`, but the `\ignorespaces` would be neutralized by `}` anyway.

Comment: Well, I tried " {\rm a~} " and this doesnt work (I changed also line 339, is that right?)... I also tried " \textrm{a}~", but @egreg I am not sure if I understand your post well, what exactly should I try to write there?

Answer (score 4):

If the `.bst` file is the one at [this link](https://code.google.com/p/bakalarka-homomorfic-encryption/source/browse/trunk/prace/czplainnat.bst?r=12), then the changes you have to do are:

1. at line 246, change

   ```
   { " {\rm a} " * t * }
   ```

   into

   ```
   { " \textrm{a}~" * t * }
   ```
2. at line 339, change

   ```
   { " a " * t * }
   ```

   into

   ```
   { " a~" * t * }
   ```
3. at line 1193, change

   ```
   { " a " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
   ```

   into

   ```
   { " a~" * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
   ```

As you are on it, also change `\sc` at line 224 into `\scshape` and `\bf` at line 117 into `\bfseries`.

Rename the file to `myczplainnat.bst` and type

```
\bibliographystyle{myczplainnat}
```

in your document, where you had `\bibliographystyle{czplainnat}`. The modified file should live next to your main document.

Raise the issue to the developers of `czplainnat.bst`.

Comment: Re point 1, should that be `\textrm{a}~\ignorespaces` instead of "just" `\textrm{a}~`?

Comment: @Mico I don't think it's necessary, as the name that follows has already leading spaces stripped off. In my comment to the question I was only describing the behavior once `~` had, which is irrelevant here.

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, I think we have a genius here! Thank you all, especially egreg... I did all those changes and it works exactly as I needed. Thaaaanks! :)